# How to fix invalid data type size in this sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: This is the image of question]

The query i wrote as

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper (
    Shopperid NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT shpr_shprid_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT shpr_shprname_nn NOT NULL,
    Gender CHAR(6) CONSTRAINT shpr_gdr_chk CHECK(Gender IN ('Male','Female')),
    MobileNo NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT shpr_mobno_nn NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Comment: And what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Error: Your query did not meet the requirement. Please check data type size.

Comment: Your CREATE command works fine, see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed447/1  I vote to close your question as unclear.

Comment: No no bro..It still throws error..

Comment: This question had been aksed in infosys training platform and shows "Please check data type size"

Comment: never store a phone number as `number`, instead use `varchar` for this purpose, because you can have phone numbers staring with `0`

Comment: You are not getting an Oracle error, the Infosys training platform is telling you it doesn't like the answer you gave. I have no idea why - it seems unlikely that it's executing the code you give it, so I imagine it's parsing it, and doesn't like something. I'd hazard a guess that it's expecting `VARCHAR2(6)` rather than `CHAR(6)`, but it might be one of the other columns - it might not be expecting `shopperid` to have that precision restriction, for instance. Either way, this isn't really an Oracle or SQL issue, it's a problem - or correct, if unhelpful - behaviour from the training platform.

Comment: Don't use `CHAR`. It's a weird ANSI-completeness checklist type that is not useful in any real application. For example - as you've defined `gender char(6)` then `Male` will be stored as `'Male  '` (2 blank spaces). You might think that would violate your constraint because surely `'Male  '` is not in `('Male','Female')`. It actually doesn't, because somewhere in the documentation there is a section about string comparison semantics with and without padding. Trust me, you don't need any of this. Make it the standard non-weird type and things will be closer to what you expect.

Comment: Agree with Alex Poole, use VARCHAR2 rather tan CHAR.  But also anything that has a length constraint is specified so would imagine that both shopperID and MobileNo should just be number with no length constraint eg MobileNo NUMBER;

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with NUMBER type definitions, try:

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper (
    Shopperid NUMBER CONSTRAINT shpr_shprid_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT shpr_shprname_nn NOT NULL,
    Gender CHAR(6) CONSTRAINT shpr_gdr_chk CHECK(Gender IN ('Male','Female')),
    MobileNo NUMBER CONSTRAINT shpr_mobno_nn NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR2(50)
);
```